# Prove $\sum \binom nk 2^k = 3^n$ this identity combinatorially

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, combinatorial-proofs

I need to prove $\sum \binom nk 2^k = 3^n$, combinatorially.

I have already proved this identity using binomial theorem, 
simply by substituting x = 1 and y = 2.

Could I get some help/tips on how to prove this combinatorially?

Comment: The binomial theorem can also be interpreted combinatorially.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered a lot of times, for example in (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/200067)

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of strings of length $n$ from the alphabet $\{a,b,c\}$, first choose how many positions in the string will be either $a$ or $b$. Call that number $k$. There are $\binom nk$ ways to select *which* $k$ positions will be $a$ or $b$ (all the other positions will be $c$), and once you have chosen a set of $k$ positions there are $2^k$ ways to choose if each of them ends up an $a$ or a $b$.